# array of 9 digit numbers convert to jpg

Tags: javascript, node.js, jpeg

I want to make a nodejs application that takes a 9 digit numbers array which represent an rgb pixel so 123456789 represent r:123, g:456, b:789 and convert it to jpg image.

so example of array is :

```
let pixels = [
  '000115166', '000115164', '000115164', '000115166', '000115166',
  '000115166', '000115166', '000115164', '000115164', '000115166',
  '000115166', '000115166', '000115166', '000115164', '000115166',
  '000115166', '000115166', '000115166', '000115166', '000115166',
  '000115164', '000115166', '000115166', '000115164', '000115164',
  '000114168', '000115166', '000114168', '000115164', '000114168']
```

is there a way to do that in nodejs app?

Comment: take a look at `node-canvas` https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas is a cairo-based nodejs implementation of the Web Canvas API

Answer (score -1):

Using **sharp** npm in node.js, we can convert image using RGB color, hope this code will help you

```
const sharp = require("sharp");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const convertImage = async () => {
  let pixels = [
    "198115166",
    "000115164",
    "000115164",
    "000115166",
    "000115166",
    "000115166",
    "000115166",
    "000115164",
    "000115164",
    "000115166",
    "000115166",
    "000115166",
    "000115166",
    "000115164",
    "000115166",
    "000115166",
    "000115166",
    "000115166",
    "000115166",
    "000115166",
    "000115164",
    "000115166",
    "000115166",
    "000115164",
    "000115164",
    "000114168",
    "000115166",
    "000114168",
    "000115164",
    "000114168",
];

const rgbData = [];
pixels.forEach((e) => {
    const obj = {
      r: e.substring(0, 3),
      g: e.substring(3, 6),
      b: e.substring(6, 9),
    };
    rgbData.push(obj);
});
const imagefolderpath = path.resolve(`${__dirname}`, "Images");
for (const color of rgbData) {
    const filename = `${uuidv4()}.jpeg`;
    await sharp({
      create: {
        width: 48,
        height: 48,
        channels: 4,
        background: { ...color },
      },
    }).toFile(filename);
  }
};

convertImage();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works except i only get the last pixel in the image file, do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: you mean get only one image in folder?

Comment: yes, like i need the pixels to be appended to one file to create the image,....what is happening now the pixel just gets overwritten and the final file is just the last pixel color